# Автоматический запуск ексель файла и макроса в нем через windows scheduler

Tags: vba, vbscript, scheduler

Как настроить открытие файла в ексель через планировщик задач знаю, но как сделать так чтобы открылся файл ексель и автоматически вызвался макрос понять не могу.

В интернете видел что-то через vbs, но там предлагали сделать как-то без открытия самого ексель файла, потом еще видел способ добавления кода вызова макроса не в модуль, а на лист, через sub `workbook_open()`, но это не подходит.

Надо именно что бы открылся ексель файл, и при этом, при открытии вызвался макрос.

Comment: Назвать этот макрос Auto_Open. Он сам запустится при открытии файла.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо воспользоваться вызовом процедуры через автозапуск Экселя:

```
Sub Auto_open()
     Procedure1 ("param1")

End Sub
```

Но надо учитывать, что система обеспечения безопасности офиса, как правило, не дает запускать скрипты. Значит нужно предварительно изменить параметры системы, чтобы обеспечить запуск.

Поэтому я для своих нужд таки написал VB-скрипт, который вызывает нужную мне процедуру "**convertXLS**" из файла .XLSM (в том же каталоге, где лежит скрипт), передавая необходимый параметр внутрь.Вот код:

```
Dim xlApp,xlBook
Dim remotePath

  remotePath = "\\server\share\2018\" 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

 macros = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\converter.xlsm"
  If (not fso.FolderExists(remotePath)) or (not fso.FileExists(macros)) Then    
   set shl = nothing
   set fso = nothing
   WScript.Quit 1
  End If

  set shl = nothing
  set fso = nothing

  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
  xlApp.Visible = true
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(macros, 0, True) 
  xlApp.Run "convertXLS",ucase(remotePath)
  xlApp.Quit 

 Set xlBook = Nothing 
 Set xlApp = Nothing
```